# How to auto update a label based on a variable that was modified by another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently trying to build a pathfinder character creator and have hit a wall. I have multiple Tabs, using `ttk.notebook`, set up in seperate files and a global variables file. I am trying to have `self.acroMod_Label` updated in `Skill_Tab.py` based on the global variable `str_mod` in the `global_variable.py` file that gets modified by using data from `Stats_Tab.py`.

`main.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from Stats_Tab import Stats_Tab
from Skills_Tab import Skills_Tab

#creates main window and nests the tabs
Class Pathfinder_GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("RPG Character Generator")
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)

        #tab creation
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self,width=760, height=480)
        self.notebook.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)

        stats_tab = Stats_Tab(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(stats_tab, text = "Stats")

        skills_tab = Skills_Tab(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(skills_tab, text = "Skills")

def main():
    Pathfinder_GUI().mainloop()

main()
```

`global_variable.py`

```
str_mod = 0

#takes score from stats_tab.Mod() and changes global variable str_mod
def abil_Mod(score):
global str_mod
str_mod = var * 2
```

`Stats_Tab.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import global_variables as gvar


class Skills_Tab(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.strMod_Var = IntVar()
        self.strength_Var = IntVar()
        self.strength_Entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.strength_Var, 
                                    width = 3,justify=CENTER)
        self.strength_Entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda event, 
                                ability = self.strength_Var, label = 
                                self.strMod_Var: self.mod(event, ability, 
                                label))
        self.strength_Entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.strMod_lbl = Label(self,textvariable = self.strMod_Var)
        self.strMod_lbl.grid(row = 2,column = 2)


   def mod(self, event, ability, label):
        #calls gvar.abil_Mod using 'score' to change gvar.str_mod and set 
        #the label to the appropriate value
        score = ability.get()
        gvar.abil_Mod(score)
        label.set(gvar.str_mod)
```

`Skills_Tab.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import global_variables as gvar

self.acroMod_Var = IntVar()
self.acroMod_Label = Label(self, textvariable = self.acroMod_Var)
self.acroMod_Label.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
```

This sets the label to 0 but I am unable to have the label update after the variable is changed.

I have done some research on the matter and have read about the `.after()`, `.trace()` and `update_idletasks()` however I am unsure if the first 2 are what I need and when I tried to use the 3rd it just gave me 2 duplicates of my frame stacked vertically one on top of the other in the window.

Comment: Your problem sounds interesting but please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe I can help you then.

Comment: to use `.trace()` you would have to create `str_mod = IntVar()`. With normal variable `str_mod = 0` you have to use `.after()` to check its value. Maybe you shouldn't put variables and tabs in separated files if you use them in the same notebook. Or you should create this variable in notebook so every tab would have access to it.

Comment: I added more code so it can be ran and duplicate the current structure of my program

Answer (score 0):

Based on the files you've provided,

> *'the global variable `str_mod` in the `global_variable.py` file that gets modified by using data from `Stats_Tab.py`*'

the assumption that `str_mod` gets modified is simply *false*.

---

Global variables are not as global as this question implies that they are. They are *not* shared, or reachable among multiple python scripts seamlessly like that.

---

If a script has a global variable, it means that variable can be reached anywhere in that script, and *that script alone* unless that script is `import`ed by another script. Even after the script with the wanted 'global' variable is `import`ed, the changes made to that variable afterward that are now for the importing script, and for the importing script *alone*.

If data in a file needs to be accessible by multiple python scripts, it has to be either *read* or *`import`ed* by each of the scripts that want to access it.

If a script needs data in a file, the script has to *read* or *`reload`*(or `import` if it's the very first time) it, *each time* the script wants to update its value to the latest.

If a script needs to change data in a file, to be accessed by another script, it has to overwrite that data in that file, or it can put it elsewhere so that the other script can access it, from the place it has been written by the first script.

---

In the below example it is assumed that some other script, or someone manually, edits `some_module` by overwriting `variable` from time to time.

You can update the `variable` defined in `some_module` to its latest value by using `reload` function. Below example updates a `label`'s text every half second using `after`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import importlib as imp         # to reload some_module after it has been imported

def show_var():
    global label
    global some_module

    try:
        imp.reload(some_module) # to reload some_module if it has already been imported
    except:
        import some_module      # to import some_module if it has never been imported

    label['text'] = some_module.variable
    label.after(500, show_var)  # to recursively call itself every 500 miliseconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    label = tk.Label(root)
    show_var()

    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

and `some_module.py`:

```
variable = 3
```

---

Using class variables (`BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, `StringVar`) may be troublesome as they require an instance of `tk.Tk()` to be able to exist.